# Is there a multi-variable distribution on the 3-torus with this characterization?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm looking to characterize anglular/circular data on the 3-torus distributed as follows:

For triplets of angles, (**X**,**Y**,**Z**), a**X** + b**Y** + c**Z** modulo 2$\pi$ is unimodal for some integers a,b,c.

Are there any known multivariate distributions that might be a good approximation to this data?  I'm looking to estimate entropy of the full and marginal distributions efficiently (with respect to the number of data samples).  Thanks!